# I am not able to install Proteus 8 professional using wine! Please help

Tags: 20.04, wine

I am trying to install Proteus 8 Professional Crack version using Wine, but I am not able to do so... I am getting error like `Proteus 8 Professional setup ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified, please run it again`. I tried it running several times, but same error occurs, but when I installed the demonstration version from the official website, it's running absolutely fine..

[image]

Comment: Is this some illegal mod version?

Comment: No i don't think as others are able to run it on their windows PC. So, i don't think it should be a problem with wine.

Comment: People here are unlikely to help you pirate software.

Comment: So, I will have to stick with the demonstration version only, that's it...The only thing is I am not able to save my files in this version as it it restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Proteues 8.x doesn't work very fine with wine. You should use proteus 7.x

See this for reference [proteus compatibility with wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1209)